# How to assert json response content using groovy?

Tags: groovy, jsonslurper

in the response of a request i have this content:

```
"comp":[
{
"type":"header",
"version":1,
"settings":
     {"logo":"mylogo",
      "logoPosition":"left",
      "inverseLogosPosition":false,
      "headerTitle":"My Report",
      "headerTitlePosition":"left",
      "pageBreak":false
}
},
```

I want to assert the content of settings.
i try this for example to assert the logoPosition = "left"

assert json.components.settings[0].logoPosition[0] == "left"

it's not working

This part is working well:

```
assert json.comp.type[0] == "header"
assert json.comp.version[0] == 1
```

Any help please, thank you

Answer (score 2):

The json provided is invalid. You can use both *paths*:

```
assert slurped.comp.settings.logoPosition[0] == "left"
assert slurped.comp[0].settings.logoPosition == "left"
```

Full example:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def json = '''{
"comp":[
    {
        "type":"header",
        "version":1,
        "settings": {
            "logo":"mylogo",
            "logoPosition":"left",
            "inverseLogosPosition":false,    
            "headerTitle":"My Report",    
            "headerTitlePosition":"left",        
            "pageBreak":false
        }
    }
]}'''

def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)

assert slurped.comp.settings.logoPosition[0] == "left"
assert slurped.comp[0].settings.logoPosition == "left"
```

Answer (score 1):

It will just be `logoPosition`, not `logoPosition[0]`

Why not have some expected json as a string, convert it to a map with JsonSlurper, then compare these?

Comment: @kirkdouglas, not mine :) Tim Yates, solved the problem first :)